# Printing with flipped coordinates

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I have a quite complex printing engine written for OS X that I need to port to iOS. Generally, it's `NSView` subclass that prints various strings and images on the paper - imagine an invoice.

Now I need to port it to iOS - my first step, of course, was to use various macros to bridge the CG/NS stuff `(e.g. NSRect<->CGRect)` and I've gotten to a point, where the view actually prints itself on the paper (using a -`viewPrintFormatter`), however, the coordinates are flipped, since Cocoa Touch uses the flipped coordinates, so the whole layout is wrong.

There's a lot of answers that flip the coordinates by applying a transform to the current context, however, this flips horizontally any text printed as well - so while the layout is correct, the text is illegible, which is a big issue.

Moving the whole engine to flipped coordinates is an option, but one that will take a lot of time as well as it would bring many other issues.

Has anyone come across this issue and solved it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can generally do this by changing the current transform without having it also flip horizontally. You simply scale the Y coordinates by -1 and then offset them by the height of your view. So your affine transformation matrix would look something like this:

```
| 1.0  0.0 | 
| 0.0 -1.0 | 
| 0.0  h   |
```

where `h` is the height of the view. So in code, it would be something like:

```
CGContextScaleCTM (context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM (context, 0.0, h);
```

(I might have the order reversed on those - I can never remember which order they go in!)

Comment: Nope, this will unfortunately flip the string as well - see http://d.pr/f/anQa - I've actually started to rework the print engine to the flipped coordinates anyway, since I do not think there's a solution to this - at least not one that doesn't involve more trickery with CG than it would simply reworking the coordinate system in the existing classes… But thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlieMonroe Reworking it may be best. However, if you want to use the above, you can set the text matrix separately by calling `CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, newMatrix);`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about this function. Guess I learn something every day. Anyway - thanks a lot for your help and I think reworking it is going to be the best way to do so anyway...